# Publishing custom package files using Laravel with composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, composer-php

I have created new package and i want to avoid publish command separately and i need to include publish command inside package composer.json file. So when package is install it should move the files according to service provider path.

I tried below method but assets/files are not published.

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan vendor:publish --provider=\"<vendorname>\\<packagename>\\<Serviceprovider>\" --tag=public --force",
        "php artisan migrate"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan vendor:publish --provider=\"<vendorname>\\<packagename>\\<Serviceprovider>\" --tag=public --force",
        "php artisan migrate"
    ]
  }
```

But it works fine when directly run the command like below

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="<vendorname>\<packagename>\<Serviceprovider>"
```

Please provide solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try with below code manually. If it returns the thing you need, then you are on the right track. Else some typo is on command of script.

```
composer run-script post-install-cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Composer does not support automatically running scripts other than those at root level. This is [somewhat contested, but doesn't look like it's going to change any time soon](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1193).

Your best bet is probably to manually run the command / instruct users to manually run the command in your readme: `composer run-script post-install-cmd -d ./vendor/[name]/[package]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use @ before command, and  also I suggesting to you to try write command in "post-autoload-dump" section. It is work for me.

```
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --provider='<vendorname>\\<packagename>\\<Serviceprovider>' --tag=public --force",
        "@php artisan migrate"
    ]
  }
```